# How can I filter a library using multiple columns?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, filter, sorting

I'm trying to filter a library using multiple columns, by project number, type, and an additional category, however when I use multiple filters, the filters applied last don't apply properly. For example, if I apply the type "pdf" filter last, some docx  items are included. If I apply the project number filter for "8" last, then some 9 10 11 items are included. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Are you using classic view or modern view? which type did you use for these fields that you use to filter? Please create a view and set filters to see if it could work.

Comment: I'm using modern view. All of the fields are choice fields, same issue when creating a view.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced that issue. However, if you are having trouble getting filters to do what you want, you could try creating a view instead.

Comment: I experience the same issue when creating a view.